# Name and graph this quadric surface in three-space.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Name and graph the equation $9x^2-y^2+9z^2-9=0$ in three-space. First, graph and name the two points dimensional coordinate trace of the surface. **Hint:** Use Plot 2D implicit and Plot 3D implicit.

Comment: "My 3D Function Graph"?

Comment: "What is that?"

Comment: A possible name for the graph. Can you be more specific when you say "name" the graph?

Answer (score 1):

This surface has the equation $9x^2-y^2+9z^2=9$. To understand what kind of quadric you have, you need to understand how it meets both the coordinate planes and axes.

- **The $xy$-plane:** The surface meets the $xy$-plane when $z=0$. In this case you have $9x^2-y^2=9$. This is a hyperbola.
- **The $xz$-plane:** The surface meets the $xz$-plane when $y=0$. In this case you have $9x^2+9y^2=9$, i.e. $x^2+y^2=1$. This is the unit circle.
- **The $yz$-plane:** The surface meets the $yz$-plane when $z=0$. In this case you have $9z^2-y^2=9$. Again, this is a hyperbola.

Already, it seems like you have a *single sheeted hyperboloid*. Let's look at how it meets the axes:

- **The $x$-axis:** The surface meets the $x$-axis when $y=z=0$. In this case you have $9x^2=9$ or $x = \pm 1$. The surface meets the $x$-axis at $(\pm 1,0,0)$.
- **The $y$-axis:** The surface meets the $y$-axis when $x=z=0$. In this case you have $-y^2=9$. This has no real solutions. The surface misses the $y$-axis.
- **The $z$-axis:** The surface meets the $z$-axis when $x=y=0$. In this case you have $9z^2=9$ or $z = \pm 1$. The surface meets the $z$-axis at $(0,0,\pm 1)$.

You should have a very good idea of what the surface looks like by now. If not, [here's a plot of it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9%2ax%5E2-y%5E2%2b9%2az%5E2=9;).